# How to use make to build a static website into a dist directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a website in an `src` directory that is several levels deep, containing html, markdown, less, coffee, png, jpg and other assets. I'd like to **build** my website into a `dist` directory using make. With build, I mean

- converting markdown files to html
- compiling coffee to js
- compiling less to css
- minifying html files
- minifying js files (that where not compiled from coffee)
- minifying css files (that where not compiled from less or sass)
- preparing images (logo.png becomes logo@1x.png logo@2x.png logo@3x.png)

I have the following file. The `cp` statements will be replaced with the respective tools to do the transformation.

```
sources = $(shell find src -type f)
t1 := $(sources:.md=.html)
t2 := $(t1:.less=.css)
targets := $(t2:.coffee=.js)
targetdirs = $(dir $(targets))

all: $(targets)

%.html: %.md
    cp $< $@

%.css: %.less
    cp $< $@

%.js: %.coffee
    cp $< $@
```

This creates outputs side by side. So `src/index.md` becomes `src/index.html`, `src/assets/stylesheets/app.less` becomes `src/assets/stylesheets/app.css` and `src/assets/scripts/app.coffee` becomes `src/assets/scripts/app.js`. What I'd like to do is change the make file such that it stores the output in the `dist` directory, so `src/index.md` is converted to `dist/index.html`, `src/assets/stylesheets/app.less` compiled to `dist/assets/stylesheets/app.css` and and `src/assets/scripts/app.coffee` becomes `dist/assets/scripts/app.js`.

So I changed the makefile as follows:

```
sources = $(shell find src -type f)
t0 := $(subst src/,dist/,$(sources:.md=.html))
t1 := $(t0:.md=.html)
t2 := $(t1:.less=.css)
targets := $(t2:.coffee=.js)
targetdirs = $(dir $(targets))

all: $(targets)

%.html: %.md
    mkdir -p $(targetdirs)
    cp $< $@

%.css: %.less
    mkdir -p $(targetdirs)
    cp $< $@

%.js: %.coffee
    mkdir -p $(targetdirs)
    cp $< $@
```

Now make fails with the following:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dist/assets/scripts/app.js', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Most examples I can find, is limited to a single directory, or compiles multiple source files into a single target.

How would one achieve this without knowing the contents of the source directory?

Environment:

- GNU Make 3.81
- OS X 10.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In make pattern rules, the stems represented by the patterns in the target and prerequisite must match *exactly*.  Take this rule:

```
%.html: %.md
        mkdir -p $(targetdirs)
        cp $< $@
```

If the target make wants to build is `dist/index.html`, then the stem is `dist/index`.  So, it will look for the prerequisite `dist/index.md`.  Which doesn't exist.  So make ignores that pattern rule as not matching, and continues to look for more implicit rules that might match... and doesn't find any so it fails.

You have to fix your rules so that the change in directory is reflected in the pattern:

```
dist/%.html: src/%.md
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        cp $< $@
```

(I'm not sure why you're creating all directories in every recipe instead of just the current one).  Now the stem for `dist/index.html` is just `index`, and the prerequisite matches `src/index.md` and it will work.

Comment: The reason for creating all those directories: being lazy... My goal was to get it to work first, and then improve later

Comment: I verified it works. Your answer also gave me the background needed to understand why it didn't work in the first place.